# Hibernate QL (and in general, SQL) 1:n relation in clause

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, kotlin, hql

I don't know how to call this problem, which is the reason I didn't know how to search for existing answers.

I have a simple 1:n relationship;
Kotlin code:

```
class Room {
    val equipments : List<Equipment>
    [...]
}

class Equipment {
    val EquipmentId : Long
    [...]
}
```

I also have a hibernate query to search for rooms with equipment:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Room r JOIN r.Equipment e WHERE r.Seats >= :Seats AND e.EquipmentId IN :Equipments ")
fun findRoomsBySeatsAndEquipment(@Param("Seats") Seats: Int, @Param("Equipments") Equipments: List<Long>): List<Room>
```

This way, all rooms that have at minimum 1 of the requested equipments, are all given back, which isn't what I want. I want the rooms that are given back to have all the given equipments and/or more, but they should not be missing one.

Is there a fancy solution to this problem? I'm using Kotlin on Spring Boot 2.0.2. and am pretty new to both. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT r
FROM Room r
WHERE r.id not in(
    SELECT e.room.id FROM Equipments e
    WHERE r.seats >= :seats AND e.id IN :equipments")
fun findRoomsBySeatsAndEquipment(@Param("seats") seats: Int, @Param("equipments") equipments: List<Long>): List<Room>
```

In my limited sql experience, join is a poor choice for finding something missing. I go with a nested search "where not in".

I took the liberty to fix the case of your variables to match kotlin&java variable naming